# How to update the information using fastapi and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am using FastAPI and SQLAlchemy. I have two ORM models users and user_profiles with foreign key relation. I am inserting data to user and user_profiles using one model

```
   #1st model.
  class User():
      __tablename__: str = "user"
   #2 Model
   class UserProfile:
      __tablename__: str = "user_profiles"
```

my user request model to update the data:

```
class UserRequest():
    user_id:str=someval()
```

My question is how I can include user_profiles model in UserRequest and update the values.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is currently no way to even determine what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by `UserRequest` you mean pydantic model, then it can be done something like this

DB Models

```py
class User(sql.Model):
   a: str = Field()
   b: str = Field()
   properties: UserProperties = ForeignKey()

class UserProperties(sql.Model):
   c: str = Field()
   d: str = Field()
```

Pydantic models

```py
class UserDTO(pydantic.BaseModel)
   a: str
   b: str

class UserPropertiesDTO(pydantic.BaseModel)
   c: str
   d: str
```

Then

```py
def request(
   a: str,
   b: str,
   c: str,
   d: str,
) -> Response:
   User.objects.create(
      **UserDTO(a, b).dict(),
      properties=UserPropertiesDTO(c, d),
   )
   return SuccessfulResponse
```

Comment: I'm confused, that looks like django syntax when creating the object?

Comment: @Thorvald yes it is, Django ORM is similar to SQLAlchemy

Comment: Yes, but that has nothing to do with FastAPI.